# Underlying methodology of web UI developement using Tailwind CSS

Tags: tailwind-css

All guides and video tutorials just show how easy and fast it is to achieve the styling using Tailwind CSS, none of them explain why they apply those classes or choose a nested `<div>` tag.

Take the first Banner template in below URL as an example, https://tailwindui.com/components/marketing/elements/banners Why a simple Banner has so many nested  tag ? can not they be combined into 1 or 2 `<div>` tags to make it much simpler and easy to read/maintain ? I just do not understand why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Tailwind is a utility framework that essentially maps 1-to-1 to vanilla CSS, understanding why they are applying certain Tailwind classes is the same as understanding the underlying CSS rules.

I would highly recommend learning to create websites using just plain HTML/CSS, and not worry about using Tailwind or other frameworks. Gaining a solid understanding of how HTML/CSS works will make it a lot easier to learn to use Tailwind and see its strengths and weaknesses.

Web.dev has a [great course on CSS fundamentals](https://web.dev/learn/css/) as well as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Front-end_web_developer). There are also plenty of other resources online that can meet you where you are.